# Remove one factor response in GT summary table after table is calculated

Tags: gtsummary

I want to produce a table reporting resistant and susceptible results. I want to calculate all results but then remove the susceptible column and keep the Resistant column for simplicity when reporting.

This is the code I have used:

```r
azith.summary.table.test <- azithromycin.to.analyse %>% 
  select(iYear, Sex, azithromycin.clean.sir) %>% 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = iYear, .tbl_fun  =   
      ~.x %>% 
      tbl_summary(
        by = azithromycin.clean.sir,
        percent = "row") %>% 
      add_n() )
```

[image: This is the resulting table]

The columns for each year are N, Resistant and Susceptible. I would like to remove Susceptible and keep only N and Resistant.

I have manually manipulated the table to show what I'm looking for.

[image: This is the desired table]

I tried the `modify_column_hide` function but I think that would remove both Resistant and Susceptible.

Any help would be appreciated.

cheers,
Callum

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use `modify_column_hide()`...example below!

```r
azith.summary.table.test <- 
  azithromycin.to.analyse %>% 
  select(iYear, Sex, azithromycin.clean.sir) %>% 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = iYear, .tbl_fun  =   
      ~ 
      .x %>% 
      tbl_summary(
        by = azithromycin.clean.sir,
        percent = "row") %>% 
      add_n() %>%
      modify_column_hide(stat_2)
  )
```

Comment: I'm very thankful! What you send got me going but didn't actually quite work. What I had to do in the end was modify_column_hide(columns = c( stat_2_1, stat_2_2, stat_2_3, stat_2_4, stat_2_5) ) . It wouldn't let me just select stat_2 for some reason.

Comment: Actually, I just found. when I moved the modify_column_hide before the add_n it worked!  i was then able to use modify_column_hid(stat_2). The add_n must split up the variable?